# Why my mobile site looks different on iPhone and Galaxy phone?

Tags: iphone, view, galaxy

I have built my mobile site and have checked how it looks on Samsung Galaxy (s3/s4) and iPhone (5).   On iPhone, it looks fine, but on Samsung galaxu (s3/s4), the page looks strange.

How can I fix this problem?

Excuse me if my post be not appropriate for right way to ask.
I'm very new here.

Thank you very much!

-MY

The website:
http://www.toshiscafe.com

Comment: you might as well be asking "why does my site look different in Internet Explorer? It looks fine in Chrome/Firefox/Safari". You've got different browsers, different rendering engines, and different underlying OSes.

Comment: Learn the ins and outs of both systems and handle it in the same manner that you would a site for IE/Firefox/Chrome

Comment: Hello Marc B,
Thank you so much for your answer! Sorry for the late reply.
I definitely have to study the differences for each browser!
I found out on Galaxy, I needed to specify the dimension of a logo image which made a table to look strange.  -Mikattyo

Comment: Hello Wayne,

Thank you for your advice, and sorry for the late reply.
Understanding the difference on each browser function is very important, I got it! Thanks!  -Mikattyo